# A-frame - Cant visualize a Json data from rest api

Tags: angular, databinding

I'm making a WebVR application with **A-frame** and **Angular**. I load some JSON data from rest api (Spring boot) and will bind it to an A-frame element. Here is an example of my JSON data.

```
"id": 0,
        "streetName": "Trg Dositeja Obradovica",
        "nameOfCity": "Novi Sad",
        "nameOfBuilding": "Fakultet tehnickih nauka",
        "geom": "GEOMETRYCOLLECTION Z (POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z (((409913.24 5010907.59 96.7548629023552,409912.99 5010908.18 96.3948629023552,409855.4 5010884.18 96.3948629023552,409855.65 5010883.58 96.7548629023552,409913.24 5010907.59 96.7548629023552))),POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z (((409913.44 5010907.11 97.0248629023552,409913.24 5010907.59 96.7548629023552,409855.65 5010883.58 96.7548629023552,409855.85 5010883.1 97.0248629023552,409913.44 5010907.11 97.0248629023552))),POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z (((409913.98 5010905.81 97.6248629023552,409913.44 5010907.11 97.0248629023552,409855.85 5010883.1 97.0248629023552,409856.39 5010881.8 97.6248629023552,409913.98 5010905.81 97.6248629023552))),POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z (((409914.3 5010905.03 97.8648629023552,409913.98 5010905.81 97.6248629023552,409856.39 5010881.8 97.6248629023552,409856.71 5010881.03 97.8648629023552,409914.3 5010905.03 97.8648629023552))),POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z (((409914.64 5010904.23 98.1448629023552,409914.3 5010905.03 97.8648629023552,409856.71 5010881.03 97.8648629023552,409857.05 5010880.22 98.1448629023552,409914.64 5010904.23 98.1448629023552))),POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z (((409915.12 5010903.07 98.4148629023552,409914.64 5010904.23 98.1448629023552,409857.05 5010880.22 98.1448629023552,409857.53 5010879.06 98.4148629023552,409915.12 5010903.07 98.4148629023552))),POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z (((409915.49 5010902.18 98.5548629023552,409915.12 5010903.07 98.4148629023552,409857.53 5010879.06 98.4148629023552,409857.9 5010878.18 98.5548629023552,409915.49 5010902.18 98.5548629023552))),POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z (((409915.71 5010901.66 98.6048629023552,409915.49 5010902.18 98.5548629023552,409857.9 5010878.18 98.5548629023552,409858.12 5010877.65 98.6048629023552,409915.71 5010901.66 98.6048629023552))),POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z (((409916.22 5010900.44 98.7148629023552,409915.97 5010901.03 98.6748629023552,409858.38 5010877.02 98.6748629023552,409858.63 5010876.44 98.7148629023552,409916.22 5010900.44 98.7148629023552))),POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z (((409917.18 5010898.13 98.6748629023552,409916.74 5010899.18 98.7648629023552,409859.15 5010875.18 98.7648629023552,409859.59 5010874.12 98.6748629023552,409917.18 5010898.13 98.6748629023552))),POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z (((409918.11 5010895.9 98.3248629023552,409917.7 5010896.88 98.4948629023552,409860.11 5010872.87 98.4948629023552,409860.52 5010871.9 98.3248629023552,409918.11 5010895.9 98.3248629023552))),POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z (((409918.5 5010894.97 98.0748629023552,409918.11 5010895.9 98.3248629023552,409860.52 5010871.9 98.3248629023552,409860.91 5010870.96 98.0748629023552,409918.5 5010894.97 98.0748629023552))),POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z (((409918.94 5010893.9 97.6748629023552,409918.5 5010894.97 98.0748629023552,409860.91 5010870.96 98.0748629023552,409861.35 5010869.89 97.6748629023552,409918.94 5010893.9 97.6748629023552))),POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z (((409919.55 5010892.45 97.1348629023552,409918.94 5010893.9 97.6748629023552,409861.35 5010869.89 97.6748629023552,409861.96 5010868.44 97.1348629023552,409919.55 5010892.45 97.1348629023552))),POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z (((409920.12 5010891.09 96.4348629023552,409919.55 5010892.45 97.1348629023552,409861.96 5010868.44 97.1348629023552,409862.53 5010867.08 96.4348629023552,409920.12 5010891.09 96.4348629023552))),POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z (((409911.01 5010927.9 112.814862902355,409909.28 5010931.95 112.824862902355,409904.61 5010929.94 112.814862902355,409906.34 5010925.9 112.814862902355,409911.01 5010927.9 112.814862902355))),POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z (((409900.01 5010921.1 112.814862902355,409901.65 5010917.28 112.804862902355,409920.12 5010925.19 112.814862902355,409917.48 5010931.37 112.824862902355,409916.27 5010934.2 112.824862902355,409913.38 5010940.95 112.824862902355,409906.81 5010938.14 112.824862902355,409903.84 5010936.87 112.824862902355,409900.19 5010935.3 112.824862902355,409897.12 5010933.99 112.824862902355,409894.9 5010933.04 112.814862902355,409897.36 5010927.28 112.814862902355,409900.01 5010921.1 112.814862902355))),POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z (((409864.68 5010959.96 87.1048629023552,409866.29 5010956.18 87.0848629023552,409875.43 5010960.09 87.1748629023552,409873.81 5010963.87 87.2048629023552,409873.67 5010963.8 87.1948629023552,409864.68 5010959.96 87.1048629023552))),POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z (((409845.29 5010952.88 89.8648629023552,409856.87 5010952.46 89.6948629023552,409862.04 5010952.44 89.7148629023552,409861.98 5010954.1 90.6448629023552,409845.37 5010954.81 90.9548629023552,409845.29 5010952.88 89.8648629023552))),POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z (((409832.6 5010966.82 99.7548629023552,409836.48 5010968.48 99.7748629023552,409840.86 5010970.35 99.7848629023552,409845.67 5010972.41 99.8048629023552,409842.85 5010978.76 100.174862902355,409842.51 5010979.54 100.214862902355,409829.76 5010974.09 100.174862902355,409830.19 5010972.99 100.114862902355,409832.6 5010966.82 99.7548629023552))),POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z (((409855.87 5010943.78 89.6348629023552,409861.1 5010946.31 89.6648629023552,409858.74 5010951.84 89.6548629023552,409857.17 5010951.17 89.6448629023552,409851.32 5010948.66 89.6048629023552,409853.42 5010943.76 89.6148629023552,409855.87 5010943.78 89.6348629023552))),POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z (((409857.53 5010903.43 87.2948629023552,409859.59 5010898.6 87.2648629023552,409863.32 5010900.2 87.3248629023552,409867.94 5010889.4 87.2548629023552,409871.97 5010891.08 87.3248629023552,409867.33 5010901.91 87.3948629023552,409886.08 5010909.94 87.7348629023552,409884.2 5010914.33 87.7648629023552,409881.17 5010921.4 87.8048629023552,409861.5 5010912.99 87.4648629023552,409841.59 5010959.52 87.7848629023552,409839.66 5010964 87.8148629023552,409838.56 5010963.49 87.7948629023552,409834.79 5010961.72 87.7248629023552,409832.92 5010960.92 87.6848629023552,409854.43 5010910.68 87.3448629023552,409857.53 5010903.43 87.2948629023552))),POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z (((409820.45 5010968.82 97.3648629023552,409830.19 5010972.99 97.3248629023552,409829.76 5010974.09 97.2248629023552,409827.61 5010979.58 96.7548629023552,409817.66 5010975.33 96.8048629023552,409820.45 5010968.82 97.3648629023552))),POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z (((409865.94 5010996.94 102.544862902355,409860.48 5010994.61 100.804862902355,409873.67 5010963.8 100.794862902355,409873.81 5010963.87 100.834862902355,409879.12 5010966.14 102.534862902355,409865.94 5010996.94 102.544862902355))),POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z (((409867.01 5010941.82 89.2448629023552,409850.5 5010942.12 89.2148629023552,409850.53 5010944.04 89.2148629023552,409853.42 5010943.76 89.2148629023552,409851.32 5010948.66 89.2048629023552,409857.17 5010951.17 89.2048629023552,409856.87 5010952.46 89.2048629023552,409845.29 5010952.88 89.1848629023552,409842.85 5010958.58 89.1648629023552,409841.59 5010959.52 89.1648629023552,409861.5 5010912.99 89.3048629023552,409881.17 5010921.4 89.3248629023552,409881.03 5010921.74 89.3248629023552,409869.37 5010948.98 89.2348629023552,409866.99 5010943.76 89.2448629023552,409867.01 5010941.82 89.2448629023552))),POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z (((409827.61 5010979.58 96.4948629023552,409829.76 5010974.09 96.5848629023552,409842.51 5010979.54 96.5848629023552,409840.12 5010984.93 96.4948629023552,409833.09 5010981.93 96.4948629023552,409830.25 5010980.72 96.4948629023552,409827.61 5010979.58 96.4948629023552))),POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z (((409876.82 5010956.85 100.804862902355,409884.68 5010938.47 100.774862902355,409890.02 5010940.75 102.494862902355,409882.15 5010959.13 102.514862902355,409876.82 5010956.85 100.804862902355))),POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z (((409900.01 5010921.1 85.2148629023552,409897.36 5010927.28 85.2048629023552,409896.84 5010928.51 85.2048629023552,409881.03 5010921.74 85.1048629023552,409881.17 5010921.4 85.1048629023552,409884.2 5010914.33 85.1148629023552,409900.01 5010921.1 85.2148629023552))),POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z (((409836.48 5010968.48 86.9948629023552,409838.56 5010963.49 87.0348629023552,409839.66 5010964 86.9348629023552,409842.92 5010965.53 86.6348629023552,409840.86 5010970.35 86.6048629023552,409836.48 5010968.48 86.9948629023552))),POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z (((409842.51 5010979.54 97.5848629023552,409842.85 5010978.76 97.6648629023552,409854.01 5010983.36 97.6648629023552,409851.29 5010989.72 97.0848629023552,409840.12 5010984.93 97.0948629023552,409842.51 5010979.54 97.5848629023552))),POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z (((409894.34 5010972.65 100.794862902355,409881.15 5011003.45 100.764862902355,409875.87 5011001.19 102.444862902355,409899.92 5010944.99 102.494862902355,409905.27 5010947.28 100.794862902355,409897.15 5010966.27 100.774862902355,409894.34 5010972.65 100.794862902355))),POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z (((409869.28 5010998.38 104.344862902355,409872.2 5010999.62 104.314862902355,409870.49 5011003.62 103.024862902355,409867.57 5011002.37 103.054862902355,409869.28 5010998.38 104.344862902355))),POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z (((409834.79 5010961.72 86.5548629023552,409838.56 5010963.49 87.0348629023552,409836.48 5010968.48 86.9948629023552,409832.6 5010966.82 86.5048629023552,409832.63 5010966.75 86.5148629023552,409834.79 5010961.72 86.5548629023552))),POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z (((409906.81 5010938.14 112.554862902355,409904.88 5010942.65 110.614862902355,409901.91 5010941.38 110.614862902355,409903.84 5010936.87 112.554862902355,409906.81 5010938.14 112.554862902355))),POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z (((409855.87 5010943.78 89.2348629023552,409866.99 5010943.76 89.2048629023552,409869.37 5010948.98 89.1748629023552,409866.29 5010956.18 89.1548629023552,409864.68 5010959.96 89.1448629023552,409859.29 5010972.55 89.1048629023552,409842.92 5010965.53 89.1848629023552,409839.66 5010964 89.1948629023552,409841.59 5010959.52 89.2048629023552,409842.85 5010958.58 89.2048629023552,409845.29 5010952.88 89.2248629023552,409845.37 5010954.81 89.2148629023552,409861.98 5010954.1 89.1748629023552,409862.04 5010952.44 89.1848629023552,409856.87 5010952.46 89.1948629023552,409857.17 5010951.17 89.2048629023552,409858.74 5010951.84 89.1948629023552,409861.1 5010946.31 89.2148629023552,409855.87 5010943.78 89.2348629023552))),POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z (((409845.67 5010972.41 97.0848629023552,409856.68 5010977.13 97.0948629023552,409854.01 5010983.36 97.6648629023552,409842.85 5010978.76 97.6648629023552,409845.67 5010972.41 97.0848629023552))),POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z (((409853.42 5010943.76 90.6748629023552,409850.53 5010944.04 90.8148629023552,409850.5 5010942.12 89.7348629023552,409867.01 5010941.82 89.6548629023552,409866.99 5010943.76 90.7548629023552,409855.87 5010943.78 90.7048629023552,409853.42 5010943.76 90.6748629023552))),POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z (((409820.45 5010968.82 97.2848629023552,409823.08 5010962.66 96.8248629023552,409832.63 5010966.75 96.8348629023552,409832.6 5010966.82 96.8448629023552,409830.19 5010972.99 97.2948629023552,409820.45 5010968.82 97.2848629023552))),POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z (((409854.43 5010910.68 82.9948629023552,409852.46 5010909.84 82.9548629023552,409855.56 5010902.58 82.9148629023552,409857.53 5010903.43 82.9548629023552,409854.43 5010910.68 82.9948629023552))),POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z (((409876.82 5010956.85 103.184862902355,409882.15 5010959.13 104.524862902355,409879.12 5010966.14 104.534862902355,409873.81 5010963.87 103.194862902355,409875.43 5010960.09 103.184862902355,409876.82 5010956.85 103.184862902355))),POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z (((409893.58 5010942.28 104.714862902355,409896.44 5010943.5 104.704862902355,409899.92 5010944.99 104.694862902355,409875.87 5011001.19 104.724862902355,409872.2 5010999.62 104.734862902355,409869.28 5010998.38 104.744862902355,409865.94 5010996.94 104.764862902355,409879.12 5010966.14 104.744862902355,409882.15 5010959.13 104.744862902355,409890.02 5010940.75 104.734862902355,409893.58 5010942.28 104.714862902355))),POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z (((409896.44 5010943.5 101.504862902355,409893.58 5010942.28 101.524862902355,409894.31 5010940.55 101.184862902355,409897.17 5010941.77 101.164862902355,409896.44 5010943.5 101.504862902355))),POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z (((409897.12 5010933.99 88.6048629023552,409900.19 5010935.3 88.6348629023552,409899.28 5010937.42 88.6548629023552,409896.22 5010936.11 88.6248629023552,409897.12 5010933.99 88.6048629023552))),POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z (((409917.48 5010931.37 85.2748629023552,409920.27 5010932.57 85.2548629023552,409919.07 5010935.39 85.1548629023552,409916.27 5010934.2 85.1748629023552,409917.48 5010931.37 85.2748629023552))),POLYHEDRALSURFACE Z (((409894.34 5010972.65 85.3648629023552,409897.15 5010966.27 85.2548629023552,409898.58 5010966.88 85.2648629023552,409895.84 5010973.29 85.3748629023552,409894.34 5010972.65 85.3648629023552))))",
        "legalStatus": "Registrovan po zakonu o legalizaciji zgrada",
        "idUsage": 1,
        "nameOfUsage": "Obrazovna ustanova"
    }
```

My code:

```
<a-scene inspector="url: https://aframe.io/releases/0.3.0/aframe-inspector.min.js">
    <a-assets>

    </a-assets>


    <a-entity *ngFor="let building of lstBuildings; let i = index" [attr.id]="building.id"
              [attr.position]="building.geom"
              visible="true" mixin="null" color="pink"
              text="zOffset:0;value:S;height:100;width:100;align:center"></a-entity>
  </a-scene>
```

The problem is i can't show the 3D buildings

Any idea, how to solve this?

Comment: Please add error message to yout question as text, not as a picture.

Comment: I have no mistake @TomazicM

Comment: Then whatever it is 'the result I get'.

Comment: I updated the question @TomazicM